# How to add website visitors to a pool?

Tags: mining-pools, webminer

As an experiment, I will have website visitors mine litecoins. Yes, I know this won't work very well, but I simply want to try it. If I want the visitors to be part of a pool, how should I create user accounts for them? **Is it ok if I have them all mine under the same worker name, or do I have to create individual workers?**

Answer (score 1):

This kinda thing gets your website put in blacklists.

The only way (I know of at least) to mine in the browser is [Bitcoin Plus](http://www.bitcoinplus.com/), which actually is just a wrapper around a background Java applet. So you would probably want to make a Java miner and then work off that.